# How to fix Valueerror in python, scaling in machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am learning machine learning. while learning the KMN algorithm scaling of data was required. when I applied it, it gave me value error.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\admin\Documents\milemarkers.csv')
df.head()
->
OBJECTID    REF_PT_ID   HWY     REF_PT_NUM  ROUTE_ID_RIMS
0   10060   52.000  14  52.000000   192
1   10061   54.167  29  54.167000   14
2   10062   122.000     94  122.000000  15
3   10063   0.000   48  0.000000    229
4   10064   196.014     29  196.014008  14

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(df)
scaled_features = scaler.transform(df)
df_feat = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features,columns = df.columns[:-1])
```

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (9738, 5), indices imply (9738, 4)
```

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: Is `scaled_features` shape (9738, 5)? If so, why are you only passing four columns - `df.columns[:-1]`?

Comment: Were you supposed to include the `OBJECTID` values? Were they meant to be scaled?

Answer (score 0):

isnt it just bcs of you ignoring the last column? it's obvious by using [:-1] you just make it (9738,4)
the correct form would be

```
df_feat = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features,columns = df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you were supposed to scale the OBJECTID column

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
```

Select the features and scale them

```
features = df.iloc[:,1:]
scaler.fit(features)
scaled_features = scaler.transform(features)
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(data=scaled_features,columns=df.columns[1:])

>>> scaler.mean_
array([84.8362   , 42.8      , 84.8362016, 92.8      ])
>>> scaler.scale_    #std
array([67.76082634, 27.78056875, 67.76082897, 96.81198273])
```

Add the columns from the original dataframe that weren't scaled.

```
missing = df.columns.difference(df_scaled.columns)
df_scaled[missing] = df[missing]
df_scaled = df_scaled.reindex(columns=df.columns)    #re-order the columns

>>> df_scaled
   OBJECTID  REF_PT_ID       HWY  REF_PT_NUM  ROUTE_ID_RIMS
0     10060  -0.484590 -1.036696   -0.484590       1.024667
1     10061  -0.452610 -0.496750   -0.452610      -0.813949
2     10062   0.548456  1.843015    0.548455      -0.803620
3     10063  -1.251995  0.187181   -1.251995       1.406851
4     10064   1.640739 -0.496750    1.640739      -0.813949
```

---

DATA

```
data = '''{"OBJECTID":{"0":10060,"1":10061,"2":10062,"3":10063,"4":10064},
           "REF_PT_ID":{"0":52.0,"1":54.167,"2":122.0,"3":0.0,"4":196.014},
           "HWY":{"0":14,"1":29,"2":94,"3":48,"4":29},
           "REF_PT_NUM":{"0":52.0,"1":54.167,"2":122.0,"3":0.0,"4":196.014008},
           "ROUTE_ID_RIMS":{"0":192,"1":14,"2":15,"3":229,"4":14}}'''
df = pd.read_json(data)
```